# Regular expression replace preg_replace() to remove 2 letter at beginning Eexcept NW/SE etc. direction markers

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I am dealing with a relatively inconsistent and messy data source, and need some help with a very specific regular expression.

A lot of the strings we get are prepended with 2 letter alphanumeric (upper or lower cases) followed by a space, that we need to purge, so we can do something like the following:

```
$town = "PE Springfield" // truncate to "Springfield"
$town = "Kr Nashville" // truncate to "Nashville"
```

But in some cases the prefixes are directives such as NE, Sw etc. which we need to keep.

```
$town = "NW Brockvillle" // keep to "NW Brockville"
$town = "Se Nashville" // uppercase to " SE Nashville"
```

I could write a more complex series of if/else statements to process the direction strings separately then merge it back,  but I'm hoping there is a brilliant regular expression.

The regex I have so far for NW/NE matching (all cases) or any 2 alphanumeric opening followed by space is:

```
$cleanpattern[] = '/^[Nn][Ww]\s/';
$cleanpattern[] = '/^[Nn][Ee]\s/';
$cleanpattern[] = '/^[Ss][Ww]\s/';
$cleanpattern[] = '/^[Ss][Ee]\s/';
$cleanpattern[] = '/^[A-Za-z]{2}\s/';
```

*Note that by some grace, this data source never supplies just N, S, E or W (single letter). But I suppose it doesn't hurt to cover that just in case for future?*

Then for replacement strings, I have the following array (whether the Sw/ne comes in lower or upper, I want them all uppercase):

```
$replacementpattern[] = 'NW ';
$replacementpattern[] = 'NE ';
$replacementpattern[] = 'SW ';
$replacementpattern[] = 'SE ';
$replacementpattern[] = '';
```

When I run the `preg_replace($cleanpattern, $replacementpattern, $town, 1)` the problem is that after the NW/SE etc. are checked and set, they are then purged by the 5th rule. Turns out the 4th parameter of "LIMIT" on this function doesn't limit the loop within the pattern/replace arrays, but rather only how many replacements are done within each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you "could" do it, not saying it's "great"...

### RegEx

```
^(((?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)\s)|[a-z]{2}\s)
```

Capture the valid cases and invalid ones in separate capture groups, then in the replacement only output the valid ones.

### Example

Here we also use a callback to uppercase the letters as needed.

```
<?php
$tests = [
    "PE Springfield", // truncate to "Springfield"
    "Kr Nashville", // truncate to "Nashville"
    "NW Brockvillle", // keep to "NW Brockville"
    "Se Nashville" // uppercase to " SE Nashville"
];

foreach ($tests as $subject) {
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/^(((?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)\s)|[a-z]{2}\s)/i', 
        function ($groups) {
            return isset($groups[2]) ? strtoupper($groups[2]) : '';
        }, $subject);
    echo "$subject = $result\n";
}
```

### Output

```
PE Springfield = Springfield
Kr Nashville = Nashville
NW Brockvillle = NW Brockvillle
Se Nashville = SE Nashville
```

### Detailed RegEx breakdown

#### Search

Options: Case insensitive;

Assert position at the beginning of the string «`^`»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number `1` «`(((?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)\s)|[a-z]{2}\s)`»

- Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`((?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)\s)`»

  - Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number `2` «`((?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)\s)`»

    - Match the regular expression below «`(?:NW|NE|SW|SE|N|E|S|W)`»

      - Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`NW`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`NE`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`SW`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`SE`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`N`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`E`»
      - Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «`S`»
      - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «`W`»
    - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «`\s`»
  - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «`[a-z]{2}\s`»

    - Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «`[a-z]{2}`»

      - Exactly 2 times «{2}»
    - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «`\s`»

#### Replacement

```
$2
```

Just output backreference #2

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I also went ahead to carefully read about the function preg_replace_callback() on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php and it all makes sense now - to return both matches, but output back only one of them for the partial exclusion mechanism! Neatly packaged into a single function into my system. Thank you!

Comment: I actually think your solution is "GREAT" Dean despite your hesitation. My backup plan was to write two separate functions, set variables on whether the first one filtered something out or not, and move onto next.. definitely not optimal. This is very elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Not different than @Dean's great approach (`preg_replace_callback` and a capture group) but with a kind of magic in the pattern to avoid alternations. The goal: no need to test if the capture group exists in the callback since it always succeeds.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '~^([ns]?[ew]?\b ?)(?:^[a-z]{2} )?~mi',
    fn($m) => strtoupper($m[1]),
    $str
);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/XiUcL)

Explanation:

In the capture group `([ns]?[ew]?\b ?)` all is optional except the word-boundary `\b`. This word-boundary succeeds in two cases:

- between a letter and the space (at least one letter is matched)
- at the start of the string when the letters and the space aren't matched in this group.

Consequences for this capture group:

- letters are always followed by a space
- a space without at least one letter before isn't possible
- even if nothing is matched, the capture group succeeds with an empty string.

When the capture group matches the empty string, the optional non-capturing group `(?:^[a-z]{2} )?` can eventually succeed. Note that it starts with the `^` anchor to be sure that the capture group before it is empty, and the word-boundary isn't a problem since it succeeds between the start of the string and the first letter of the non-capturing group, obviously, when the capturing group isn't empty, `^` fails and the non-capturing group too.